# How to access to generic class field via scala-reflect and TypeTag (Scala 2.10)

Tags: scala, scala-reflect, scala-generics

I am trying to check if a field exists in a generic class.

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}    
class Example[T:ru.TypeTag](val value:T)

object Example {
  def apply[T:ru.TypeTag](value:T, fieldName: String) : Example[T] = {
    val t = ru.typeOf[T]
    val hasField: Boolean = ??? // HOW CAN I CHECK THAT class T has the field with name fieldName?

    if(hasField)
      new Example(value)
    else
      throw new RuntimeException()
  }
}

case class Foo(field:String)
object Test{
  Example(Foo("hola"), "field") // WILL WORK
  Example(Foo("hola"), "other") // THROWS EXCEPTION
}
```

How can I implement this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[scala](/questions/tagged/scala) 2.10:

```
val hasField = t.declarations.exists { _.name.decodedName.toString == fieldName }
```

[scala](/questions/tagged/scala) 2.11:

```
val hasField = t.decls.exists { _.name.decodedName.toString == fieldName }
```

*edit: didn't notice the Scala 2.10 requirement at first*

Comment: You aren't checking it's a field. It would also return true if there is a method or a type member with this name.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov is totally right!  You can use the `isXXX` methods on `universe.Symbol` to filter accordingly: `t.declarations.exists { x => !x.isMethod && ...}`